# Why doesn't KDE see the bold version of Droid Sans Monospace, but GNOME does?

Tags: kde, fonts

I'm trying to set all my terminals to use the Droid Sans Monospace font from the package ttf-droid. In GNOME, this works perfectly, but KDE's Konsole does not seem to see the bold version of the font. When I look in the font settings, the bold and bold oblique versions of the font do not show up in the list. Why can't KDE find the bold version of Droid Sans Mono?

I'm asking on this website because the answer may lie in the way the Droid fonts or KDE were packaged for Ubuntu, so the answer may be Ubuntu-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I don't believe there are Bold variants of the Droid Sans Mono font (just Droid Serif and Droid Sans; see [here](http://damieng.com/blog/2007/11/14/droid-font-family-courtesy-of-google-ascender). The package I have installed certainly doesn't have bold versions. What you are seeing are probably "fake bold", made by darkening the usual versions algorithmically. I'm not a KDE/Konsole user, but I suspect it (really, probably Qt) does not have the capacity for creaking fake bolds, but perhaps Gtk/GNOME/gnome-terminal does.

Comment: The existence of [this patch](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/FakeBold+Font+patches+for+QT+4.5.x?content=64029) would seem to support your answer.