# I cannot set DejaVu Sans Mono in gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, fonts

### The problem:

When I try to select the font, there is no regular **DejaVu Sans Mono**, only the bold, book, and oblique variations. Here a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww6hi.png). However, LibreOffice Writer shows the font, and I can use it without any issue on it.

I installed all the ttf-dejavu packages `sudo apt install ttf-dejavu*`

### My System:

Ubuntu 19.04 64-bit. GNOME 3.32.1

### Not so related questions:

- I don't want a possibly "fake" variation, but the regular font: [cannot see bold in gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13906/why-doesnt-kde-see-the-bold-version-of-droid-sans-monospace-but-gnome-does)
- The OP starts saying that is able to see the font in gnome-terminal: [ttf-dejavu fonts in xlsfonts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15780/how-does-one-get-the-ttf-dejavu-fonts-to-show-up-in-xlsfonts-for-use-in-rxvt)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This issue is not specific to gnome-terminal in particular, e.g. gedit also offers the same variants of DejaVu Sans Mono. (Gedit also lists non-monospaced fonts while the Terminal filters them out, but that's not the issue here.) On the other hand the Terminal and Gedit offer variants that LibreOffice don't. So it's a more generic difference between how GNOME software vs. LibreOffice handle fonts. Or maybe they just call them differently, isn't DejaVu Sans Mono Book the font you're looking for?

Comment: Note that the two "not so related questions" and their answers date back to 2010, presumably a lot has changed since then.

Comment: @egmont Thanks for the complementary information. To your question: no, the book variation is narrower than the regular

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install fonts-dejavu
on my Ubuntu 20.04